# Elm Guide Dice Exercise

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I'm doing the Elm Guide exercise from Random Section and got stuck in step 5, where I have to flip around the dices before they settle on a final Value. I'm trying to do this calling the Cmd, that updates the view with the new values of the dices, 10 times with just one click of the button "Roll!" and put some kind of sleep function before each iteraction. For what I've read, Elm does not have a for, loop or while statement. The only way to loop is through recursion, but I'm not being able to adapt my code for it. My code below, does anyone have a suggestion?

```
import Browser
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Svg exposing (..)
import Svg.Attributes as SvgAttr exposing (..)
import Random



-- MAIN


main =
  Browser.element
    { init = init
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    , view = view
    }



-- MODEL


type alias Model =
  { dieFace : Int
  , dieFace2 : Int
  }


init : () -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init _ =
  ( Model 1 1
  , Cmd.none
  )



-- UPDATE


type Msg
  = Roll
  | NewFace (Int, Int)


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Roll ->
      ( model
      , Random.generate NewFace randomPair
      )

    NewFace (newFace, newFace2) ->
      ( Model newFace newFace2
      , Cmd.none
      )

weightedRoll : Random.Generator Int
weightedRoll =
  Random.weighted
          (1, 1)
          [ (10, 2) 
          , (10, 3) 
          , (10, 4)
          , (20, 5)
          , (40, 6)
          ]
          
          
randomPair : Random.Generator (Int, Int)
randomPair = 
  Random.pair (Random.int 1 6) (Random.int 1 6)
    
    
  
    

-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  Sub.none



-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div [] 
      [ h1 [] [ Html.text (String.fromInt model.dieFace) ]
      , svg
          [ width "120"
          , height "120"
          , viewBox "0 0 120 120"
          ]
        (List.append
          [ rect
            [ x "10"
            , y "10"
            , width "100"
            , height "100"
            , rx "15"
            , ry "15"
            ]
            []
          ]
          (dicesSVG model.dieFace)
        )
      , div []
            [ h1 [] [Html.text (String.fromInt model.dieFace2) ]
            , svg
          [ width "120"
          , height "120"
          , viewBox "0 0 120 120"
          ]
        (List.append
          [ rect
            [ x "10"
            , y "10"
            , width "100"
            , height "100"
            , rx "15"
            , ry "15"
            ]
            []
          ]
          (dicesSVG model.dieFace2)
        )]
      , button [onClick Roll] [Html.text "Roll!"]
      ]
    
    
dicesSVG : Int -> List (Svg Msg)
dicesSVG number =
  case number of
    1 ->
      [ circle [cx "60", cy "60", r "10", fill "white" ] [] ]
      
    2 ->
      [ circle [ cx "35", cy "35", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "85", cy "85", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      ]
      
    3 ->
      [ circle [ cx "35", cy "35", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "60", cy "60", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "85", cy "85", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      ]
      
    4 ->
      [ circle [ cx "35", cy "35", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "85", cy "35", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "35", cy "85", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "85", cy "85", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      ]
      
    5 ->
      [ circle [ cx "35", cy "35", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "85", cy "35", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "60", cy "60", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "35", cy "85", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "85", cy "85", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      ]
      
    6 ->
      [ circle [ cx "35", cy "35", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "85", cy "35", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "35", cy "60", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "85", cy "60", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "35", cy "85", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      , circle [ cx "85", cy "85", r "10", fill "white" ] []
      ]
      
    _ ->
      []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is mostly in asking the runtime to send you messages.

The first thing you could try is changing

```
  NewFace (newFace, newFace2) ->
      ( Model newFace newFace2
      , Cmd.none
      )
```

to

```
  NewFace (newFace, newFace2) ->
      ( Model newFace newFace2
      , Random.generate NewFace randomPair
      )
```

This has the problem of never stopping, making your program spin around forever...

So you will need to track some stopping condition. Perhaps add a field to your model that tracks how many times it has rolled already? Then switching between `Random.generate` and `Cmd.none` based on that field.

---

Finally if you want a time delay between the rolls, then

```
import Task


wait : Float -> msg -> Cmd msg
wait delay msgToCallWhenDone =
  Task.perform (always msg) (Process.sleep delay)
```

will give you a `Cmd` that will call whatever msg you give it after `delay` milliseconds. As a hint, you might want to introduce another msg for this one.